# Android deep links not redirecting to app when opened from gmail and redirecting

Tags: android, gmail, applinks

I have the following scenario:
I have app.myapp.com that is both a PWA and app link host for my app. Also I have api.myapp.com that serves as the backend for the app, all the requests are sent to the api domain.
When I verify the email address of the user, than a verification link is sent to them via email like this: https://api.myapp.com/verifyEmail/token/asd123
When they click on it, the backend verifies the token and if it is valid, then it sends an HTTP redirect to https://app.myapp.com/email-verified. Since this is an app link domain, if the user has my app installed, then the app will open with the appropriate page (congrats, email is verified).
But when the user uses the Gmail app and has the embedded browser enabled in gmail, then this embedded browser will not recognize the new domain after the redirect and will not try to open my app. If I turn on the embedded browser, then everything works flawlessly as it should.
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Do you found any workaround as I am also facing same.